# What happened to IConvertible in PCL Profile111?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, portable-class-library, dnx, dnx50

All I did was disable support for Silverlight 5 in my PCL project.

Visual Studio 2015.1 then informed me that it decided to support ASP.NET Core 5.0 as well (which I don't want or need) added crap like `project.json` to the project and the code using `IConvertible` stopped compiling due to `The type or namespace name 'IConvertible' could not be found` error.

How can I fix this mess? I want to be able to use both `IConvertible` and `Parallel.For`.

Comment: Do you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @user1829325 No. It is a known bug: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5422. Microsoft doesn't care about supporting slightly older platforms.

Comment: @user1829325 I am going to use a custom Parallel.For when I need it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48804/implementation-of-parallel-foreach-for-net-3-5